# stuck trying to compute variance of continuous random variable

Tags: probability, proof-verification, expected-value, variance

I'm stuck on a problem where I'm asked to calculate the variance of the continuous RV with pdf $kx^3$ for $0 \leq x \leq 2$ and 0 elsewhere.

The value I find for E($X^2$) is much smaller than what I find for E(X)$^2$, so V(X) = E(X$^2$) - E(X)$^2$ turns out to be negative, which I have read is invalid and indicates that I have made a mistake somewhere - but I just can't see where I'm going wrong.

First I'm asked to find the value of k which makes the function a valid PDF:

$$\begin{align*}
  1
  &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} kx^3\ dx\\
  &= \int_0^2 kx^3\ dx\\
  &= k \int_0^2 x^3\ dx\\
  &= \frac{kx^4}{4} \Big|_0^2\\
  &= k \left(\frac{2^4}{4} - \frac{0^4}{4}\right)\\
  &= k (4 - 0)\\
  &= 4k\\
  k &= \frac{1}{4}
  \end{align*}$$

Next I try to find E(X) and E(X$^2$) in preparation to set up the equation for V(X):

$$\begin{align*}
 E(X)
 &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \cdot f(x)\ dx\\
 &= \int_0^2 x \cdot 4x^3\ dx\\
 &= 4 \int_0^2 x^4\ dx\\
 &= 4 \frac{x^5}{5} \Big|_0^2\\
 &= 4 \left(\frac{2^5}{5} - \frac{0^5}{5}\right)\\
 &= 4 \left(\frac{32}{5} - 0\right)\\
 &= \frac{128}{5}\\
 &= 25.6
 \end{align*}$$

$$\begin{align*}
 E(X^2)
 &= \int_0^2 x^2 \cdot \frac{1}{4} x^3\ dx\\
 &= \frac{1}{4}  \int_0^2 x^5\ dx\\
 &= \frac{x^6}{4 \cdot 6} \Big|_0^2\\
 &= \frac{1}{24} (2^6 - 0^6)\\
 &= \frac{64}{24}\\
 &= \frac{8}{3}\\
 &= 2.\overline{6}
 \end{align*}$$

Finally, I plug these values into the equation for V(X) and get what appears to be an invalid answer:

$$\begin{align*}
 V(X)
 &= E(X^2) - E(X)^2\\
 &= 2.\overline{6} - 25.6^2\\
 &= 2.\overline{6} - 655.36\\
 &= -652.69\overline{3}
\end{align*}$$

Thanks for your attention and in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is when you compute $E[X]$, you are using $k=4$ rather than $\frac14$, hence the larger value.

$$E[X]=\frac{32}{20}=\frac{8}{5}$$

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thank you! I'm not able to accept your answer for another few minutes.